# Are .fsx files interactively compiled in debug or release mode?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

When launching a .fsx with fsi.exe, does the code is compiled interactively in debug or release mode?

Because I did fsi.exe --debug test.fsx and it still prints "release".

test.fsx:

```
...
    #if DEBUG
        do printf "debug"
    #else
        do printf "release"    
    #endif
...
```

Did I miss something? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that `--debug` implies `--define DEBUG`, just that e.g. debugging symbols and such will be there.

Comment: Ok, but now suppose I don't define DEBUG or RELEASE, what does fsi in term of compilation? Is F# code interactively compiled in Release or Debug mode?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking - what does "release mode" or "debug mode" mean to you? For example, when using the default project templates, the two configurations have a variety of differences (e.g. 'Debug' generates debugging symbols, turns off compiler optimizations and tailcalls, defines DEBUG, ...) where each of these aspects corresponds to some command-line option on fsc.exe. A similar thing applies to fsi.exe - there are a bunch of command-line options for controlling each of these aspects.

Comment: Yes, exactly I meant that (release mode = all possible optimizations on). I know for instance that --tailcalls is on by default. What about others like --optimize? So my question would be more "Have I to call --optimize+" (if I want to be in the same condition than a release build)?

Comment: I don't remember what the defaults are (and I don't see it in the --help), so I would just explicitly turn on/off all those.  You can always create a tiny project in Release mode, build, and then inspect the output window to get the compiler command-line and copy the corresponding fsc.exe flags.